# "insert to" versus "insert at"

Tags: prepositions

Which is correct or most preferred?

> insert the item **at** the beginning of the list

or

> insert the item  **to** the beginning of the list

Comment: 1. You don't "insert" at the beginning. 2. If you have to use the word *insert* for other reasons, then say "insert **at** the beginning." The other alternative of "insert to" is incorrect.

Comment: @vth " insert at " is not incorrect and has its uses. As in "insert at the center" or "insert at the fourth place".

Comment: In a programming or computer science context, **insert at** would be the most natural use. In other contexts, maybe “in” or “into” would be better (depending on the meaning).

Comment: I have deleted my initial comment following suggestions made by Kris and the answer provided by Jason Bassford . After further research, yes, both *insert to* and *insert at* is correct, the latter of which somehow does not even get so much as a mention in most major online dictionaries, which is why I made the false conclusion in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just between the two examples, **insert at** is the more common.

It would typically be used in a technical context.

---

Here are three examples from Microsoft.

[Text.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-insert):

> **Arguments**    **Description**
> offset                  The index to insert at.

[ParameterBindingRulesCollection.Insert Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/jj127080(v=vs.118)):

> Parameters
>
> - index
>   Type: System.Int32
>    
>   index to insert at.

[ImmutableArray.Insert Method (Int32, T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn628241(v=vs.111).aspx):

> *item*
>  
>       Type: T
>       The item to insert at the start of the array.

And an example from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/insertNode):

> The **Range.insertNode()** method inserts a node at the start of the `Range`.
>
> The new node is inserted at the start boundary point of the `Range`.

---

As somebody who's worked a long time in the technical field, inserting items **at** the beginning of a list sounds natural to me.

However, if you're not talking about a *specific* list location, but a list in general, it would be more common to say:

> Insert the item **into** the list.

Comment: I can only assume that this excellent answer got a downvote because you used a Microsoft example instead of Python :)